# How to extract metadata from docx, txt and rtf files in Android

Tags: android, metadata, docx, rtf, txt

Please suggest how it is possible to extract metadata like author, title, creator, creationDate, etc. from docx, txt and rtf file types in Android?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my question, since there's no answer. I hope someone it may help.

Library to get metadata from **DOCX/DOC** files - https://poi.apache.org/
In case of DOCX you have to pass InputStream to XWPFDocument object - XWPFDocument(inputStream), in case of DOC - HWPFDocument(inputStream).

For **PDF** files - https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android or paid https://pspdfkit.com/

For **TXT** files there's no extended metadata.